# HTML table attributes ignored

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add a table to a php page template.
The headers and cells contents show well, but the table attributes are being ignored.

This code:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="10">  
<tr>
<th>Name</th><span/>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>name_1</td>
<td>name_2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

produces the following result:

```
Name  Address
name_1name_2
```

I get no border and no spacing (the headers are bolded, I just couldn't do it here).

Does it have something to do with wordpress?
How can it be solved?

Comment: Wordpress removes some tags and attributes automatically yes, have you condidered styling your table with CSS ?

Comment: i believe it has to do with your themes css overwriting it, can you see the attributes in the source?

Comment: @Bainternet, I'm currently using twenty ten. Where should I look for the attributes?

Comment: @mike23, no. So styling the table with css bypasses WP?

Comment: @Ash look in the source code of the page that is generated, right click -> view source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `border="1"` attribute but leave the cellspacing. Then go into `styles.css` and either add your CSS selectors or modify the existing selectors. If your table is within the `id="content"` block, the styling is being affected by the existing selectors. The ones you will want to adjust are:

```css
#content table {
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin: 0 -1px 24px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#content tr th,
#content thead th {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 9px 24px;
}
#content tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    padding: 6px 24px;
}
#content tr.odd td {
    background: #f2f7fc;
}
```